# Dynamically set class array parameter, redbeanphp wrapper

Tags: php, oop, redbean

I'm writing a wrapper for redbeanphp orm,

basically instead of using

```
$user = R::dispense('users');
$user->name = 'Zigi marx';
R::store($user);
```

I do like so

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = 'Zigi marx';
$user->save();
```

the way this is done is,
I have a class called User that extends model
and model runs Redbeanphp

the full code of my model can be found here
http://textuploader.com/bxon

my problem is when I try to set a one to many relation,
In redbean it is done like so

```
$user = R::dispense('users');
$user->name = 'Zigi marx';

$book = R::dispense('books');
$book->name = 'Lord of the rings II';
$user->ownBooks[] = $book;
```

and in my code

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = 'Zigi marx';
$book = new Book();
$book->name = 'Lord of the rings II';
$user->ownBooks[] = $book;
```

I get this error

> Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property
>   Zigi\models\User::$ownBooks has no effect

The Answer:
 the __get function in model needed to be changed like so

```
public function & __get($name){
    $result =& $this->__bean->{$name};
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `__get` method is returning the bean property by value, and so you cannot modify it afterward. To fix it, you need to return it by reference ([see PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/language.references.pass.php)), by adding a `&` to your method definition, like so:

```
public function & __get($name){
    $result =& $this->__bean->$name;
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: When triyng that I get
Only variable references should be returned by reference

Comment: I've updated my answer, does it work by using an intermediate "by reference" variable?

Comment: It works on my PHP 5.6.4... What version are you using? Maybe try with `$result =& $this->__bean->__get($name); return $result;`?

Comment: still same error, I updated my question with the the __get and __set